# Why does this return 4? (inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance

For this code:

```
public class Demo
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      System.out.println( new B().m1()  );
   }
}

class A
{
   int m1() {return m3();}
   int m2() {return this.m3();}
   int m3() {return 1;}
}

class B extends A
{
   int m1() {return super.m1();}
   int m3() {return 4;}
   int m4() {return m2();}
}
```

This returns 4 but I am unsure why. So how I see it is: new B().m1() creates an object of type B and calls m1() method of B class, this calls super.m1() of A class, which returns m3(), which is 1. I understand you can override methods in inheritance but m1() returns m3() in class A explicitly, not in class B, so why is 4 being returned and the output and not 1?

Comment: `m1()` does **not** `returns m3()` in classA explicitly. It returns `m3()`. in this case the `m3()` overloaded in class `B` (which returns `4`). BTW, `System.out.println(new B().m2());` would also print `4`. For the same reason.

Comment: Wait I don't understand the last line: "BTW, System.out.println(new B().m2()); would also print 4. For the same reason." Class B doesn't have a m2() method? @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Yes it does. It *inherits* it from `A`.

Comment: I see okay, seems I need to watch a few more videos on inheritance @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Your class names aren't meaningful, but every `B` is an `A`. Not every `A` is a `B` (but some are).

Answer (score 2):

Java's *instance* methods are **strictly** dynamic dispatch.

Any method invocation is *always* going to hit the 'most specific' version of that method based on what the *actual type* of the `this` reference would be.

The only exception is `super.x()` which will invoke your super, but it's a one-off transfer. Any invokes done in that method do the dynamic dispatch thing same as usual.

So:

`new B().m1()` invokes B's `m1()` method, naturally: Because the actual instance's real type is, naturally, `B`.

That method will invoke A's `m1()`. A1's `m1()` code is:

```java
return m3();
```

Which is of course, short for:

```java
return this.m3();
```

and `this` here is **still an instance of `B`**. Hence, dynamic dispatch is applied and it'll be the `m3()` impl from `class B` that is invoked, thus, `4` is returned.

There is no way to avoid this short of rewriting all those methods.

2 important notes to consider:

- `static` methods don't do any of this stuff.
- In java, a method's name includes the parameter types (without generics, i.e. erased) *and* the return type. So, if you have:

```
class Parent {
  void foo(Object o) {}
}

class Child extends Parent {
  void foo(String o) {}
}

...

Parent p = new Child();
p.foo("hello!");
```

Will still invoke Parent's `foo`, not child's `foo`, because they are **not the same method**. This is why you always use `@Override` when you intend to override; this means you get a compiler error when you don't actually end up overriding because the types don't match.

Comment: I have a question. Is there any difference between B b = new B(); System.out.println( b.m1()  ); or   System.out.println( new B().m1()  );?

Comment: Zero. It'll compile to the exact same classfile (if we ignore the line number table).